# disabling click events for all elements that contain a certain class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

It seems a very straight forward problem but I cannot find a proper way of solving this. How would I be able to have one master class that disables all the click events for this element.

Let's say I have a lot of different buttons and if any of these buttons contain the class `btn-disabled` I want it to disable all the click events attached to this element.

**Example**

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-disabled', function() {
  return false;
});

$(document).on('click', '.button:not(.btn-special)', function() {
    alert('You have clicked the button!');
});

$(document).on('click', '.button.btn-special', function() {
    alert('You have clicked the special button!');
});

<div class='button'>
  Enabled Button
</div>

<div class='button btn-special'>
  Enabled Special Button
</div>

<div class='button btn-disabled'>
  Disabled Button
</div>

<div class='button btn-special btn-disabled'>
  Disabled Special Button
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1eyrpbLo/1/

I expected for the disabled buttons to not have any alerts popping up but instead they currently just work like the non-disabled buttons. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the big problems is that jQuery only attaches and listens to *bubbling* events. If you attach a listener to the document, it will only ever run *after* all intermediate listeners (between the clicked element and the document) have fired.

I'd use vanilla JS instead, so that you can attach a listener in the capturing phase, before the event captures down to the target. Then `stopPropagation` will prevent the event from reaching the target in the first place.

```
document.addEventListener(
  'click',
  (e) => {
    if (e.target.closest('.btn-disabled')) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  },
  true // attach in capturing phase
);
```

If you do this, you can then add listeners as you wish to any buttons (or even to the document) using jQuery - and any clicked buttons that happen to have a `btn-disabled` class (or an ancestor element with a `btn-disabled` class) will not have their click handlers fire, regardless of whether the listener is attached to the button or a parent element.

Comment: I learn something new everyday. Thank you, this works perfectly.